# Can there be duplicate Policy IDs?

Tags: token

> An asset is uniquely identified by an asset ID, which is a pair of both the policy ID and asset name.

The Policy ID is a hash of the monetary policy script that was used to mint the token. What prevents someone from minting more of the same tokens using the same policy script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that prevents other people to (successfully) use the same policy script is that the **policy needs to be validated by the blockchain**. Minting transactions where the policy script is not successfully validated do not go through. This can be used for instance to make the policy require that the minting transaction is signed by a specific secret key. Or the policy can require that a specific UTxO is spend within the minting transaction. The latter would make a true NFT as UTxO are unique and thus the policy can only ever evaluate once to true.

Answer (score 2):

One part of the policy is usually about signatures associated with it.

If you want to use the same script again, you will need the corresponding private keys.

If you have them and policy permits it, you can mint more tokens.

This is very important, as if your "NFT project" does not have a policy that prevents them to
mint more tokens, it is really unfair to claim one as such.